# Poisson draw in Rcpp and R different results

Tags: r, rcpp

I face the following contradiction when I use the same code in `R` and in `Rcpp`

In `R` I run the following code

```
t = 0
for(i in 1:50){
 t = t + rpois(1, 0.5)
}
t
[1] 28
```

and I take back a value `t` which is nonnegative. Now I type the exact same commands in `Rcpp`

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include<Rmath.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int Pois(int l){ 
  int t=0;
  for(int i=0; i<50;++i){
    t+=R::rpois(l);
  }
  return t;
}
```

and when I call the function in `R`

```
Pois(0.5)
[1] 0
```

which is wrong since in `R` it was different of zero

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `double l` rather than `int l`, e.g.,

```
int Pois(double l){ 
  int t=0;
  for(int i=0; i<50;++i){
    t+=R::rpois(l);
  }
  return t;
}
```

otherwise `(int) 0.5` gives you `0`.

Answer (score 4):

@ThomasIsCoding already showed you the main issue.  But recall that beside `R::rpois()` we also have the vectorised `Rcpp::rpois()`.  And, as usual, given the same seed it gives the same draws as R:

```
> set.seed(123)
> rpois(10, 0.5)
 [1] 0 1 0 1 2 0 0 1 0 0
> Rcpp::cppFunction("NumericVector myrp(int n, double l) { return Rcpp::rpois(n, l); }")
> set.seed(123)
> myrp(10, 0.5)
 [1] 0 1 0 1 2 0 0 1 0 0
>
```